# How long does it take for dns zone records to be propagated?

Tags: domain-name-system

Well, I have some understanding of how `DNS` works, but that doesn't allow me to answer this question. It must have to do with the time to live value of each particular record. But there are a bunch of timing parameters in `SOA`. So I'm not sure, which of them I should consider. Also, different `DNS` servers may treat this values differently, I take it.

So, suppose, I'm going to change domain's: 1) `IP` address, 2) `NS` servers. Is there a way to find out how much will it take? Probably if we assume that `DNS` servers respect supplied parameters.

Answer (score 1):

For caching in general the TTL value of the specific record/RRset is used.

For caching of negative responses the last value in `SOA` (the `MINIMUM` field) is used.

The above applies to all records in your own zone. And with planned changes you have the ability to lower the TTL in advance (at least the old TTL in advance) to minimize the time that old data remains valid after your changes.

As for the other timing parameters of the `SOA`, those relate to the authoritative servers in a master/slave setup.

If you are changing the delegation, however, you do not only deal with records in your own zone but also the delegatory `NS` records in the parent zone as well as any glue `A`/`AAAA` records when applicable.

Comment: So, changing `A` records takes its `TTL` values seconds? Also, could you elaborate on delegation part? It has to do with which records in the parent zone? What exactly happens there? Also, based on what do they say, that it takes 48 hours for nameserver changes to take effect, and 8 hours for `A` records? Why does propagation doesn't take one of those `TTL` values?